# Parse Server + Express - Issues with ParseError and site dying/restarting

Tags: node.js, express, parse-server, bitnami, forever

I have deployed a Bitnami Parse stack to a Google Cloud VM. This stack is basically Apache running as a proxy, Then a MEAN stack handling parse server and dashboard etc.

Everything appears to be working fine when accessing the dashboard and sending individual CURL requests to test it's all available.

However, there appears to be a fatal flaw in that. When Parse returns one of it's errors e.g.

```
{"code":101,"error":"Object not found."}
```

Express sees it as an uncaught exception and dies. Now I realise that it's intentional behaviour (There's enough information out there as to why you don't want to persist after an uncaught exception)

The Bitnami stack uses Forever to run the Parse Server, but as you can see from the logs I will include below, you still run into issues with refused connections.

```
2016-11-25T11:41:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): {"code":101,"error":"Object not found."}
2016-11-25T11:41:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to connect to X.X.X.X: Connection refused
2016-11-25T11:41:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to connect to X.X.X.X: Connection refused
2016-11-25T11:41:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to connect to X.X.X.X: Connection refused
2016-11-25T11:41:17+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to connect to X.X.X.X: Connection refused
```

Meanwhile in the Forever logs:

```
Error generating response. ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' } code=101, message=Object not found.
[object Object]
/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:425
        throw err;
        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs/parse-server.info.2016-11-25'
at Error (native)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 7
error: Script restart attempt #1
parse-server running on port 1337
parse-dashboard running on port 4040
```

So you can see that immediately following a Parse error being returned, The service is unavailable until Forever can restart the Parse Server.

This issue appears that it would affect all users as well, so if one user receives an exception, all users lose connection for a brief period.

So the question is, how should this be properly handled? Is Parse + Express not the way to go about it? Or is there some method of configuring Node or Express to return the API error to the requester, without Express dying (And without having to fall into the trap of using uncaughtException to keep Node alive)

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: isn't it just a permission error from Parse? I think Parse cannot write info log to the logs directory.

Comment: Wow, I hope it's something so simple.. However I did check the permissions on /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs/ and it is owned by the user Node is running as, and the user has write permission

Comment: I think the error log said it's `Access Error`. If it's just the development server, did you try to set the `/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs` to 777?

Comment: Okay, you might be right. Out of the box Bitnami sets the permissions as **bitnami:daemon** but Node runs as _user_ daemon (which is in the daemon group. The group doesn't have write access to the folder :facepalm:

Comment: Glad you solved it :)

Comment: :) Thanks, just testing the theory now, but it's going to be that! If you post as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs from Forever said it's `EACCES` error, that means `ParseServer` couldn't access the log file and not able to write the info log in it.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs/parse-server.info.2016-11-25'
at Error (native)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 7
error: Script restart attempt #1
parse-server running on port 1337
parse-dashboard running on port 4040
```

I think you have to change the `/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs` with proper permission so that `ParseServer` can write log files in it.

Comment: Thanks again, I've added a comment to a Bitnami community [forum post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/problem-with-logging/43612/4) on the subject.